# debugger visualizer for boost multi_array

Tags: visual-studio, boost

I am wondering if anybody has a debugger visualizer ready for boost multi_array, I am currently developing using Visual Studio 2015 but even another version would be fine eventually.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I made mine, not difficult after some research